# WPF XAML : How to disable multi selection in a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, multi-select

In a DataGrid like this :

```
<DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" Name="dataGrid"
    IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}" >
...
</Datagrid>
```

How do you disable the multi selection feature ?

(I'm sure it's simple, but I don't find it.)

Comment: I want to ask how to enable it in xaml.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Set the [DataGrid.SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectionmode(VS.95).aspx):

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" ...
```

Comment: Haa Nice Thanks a lot M.Copsey !

Answer (score 1):

set the DataGrid.MultiSelect

this.DataGrid.MultiSelect = "false"

Comment: I can't find MultiSelect on DataGrid in xaml.